# C# function for converting string to int with default value parameter

Tags: c#, type-conversion

So I was expecting to find a definitive equivalent of Delphi's StrToIntDef function on StackOverflow but I can't.

Implement the following...

```
public static int StrToIntDef(string s, int def)
{

}
```

Comment: As I see [on this link](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=StrToIntDef&ExpandCode2=Yes) this function do more than just parsing..

Comment: TryParse for Compact Framework: http://www.yortondotnet.com/2009/11/tryparse-for-compact-framework.html

Comment: Four people had no problem providing answers to this question and the answers have 27 votes between them. Looks like a "real question" to me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Regular numbers

```
public static int StrToIntDef(string s, int @default)
{
    int number;
    if (int.TryParse(s, out number))
        return number;
    return @default;
}
```

This method is using a couple of more advanced C# features which a beginner isn't likely to know, they are:

- Adding the `@` in front of default, this is to prevent a compilation error as it's a C# keyword.
- Passing in the argument `number` as `out`, this means that number will be updated within the function and returned despite being a value type.

### Different number styles

There is an [additional overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27.aspx) that can be used to parse different styles of numbers:

```
public static bool TryParse(
    string s,
    NumberStyles style,
    IFormatProvider provider,
    out int result
)
```

Here is the list of `NumberStyles` that can be used in conjunction with this overload to parse abnormally formed numbers like currency or hex.

- `None`
- `AllowLeadingWhite`
- `AllowTrailingWhite`
- `AllowLeadingSign`
- `AllowTrailingSign`
- `AllowParentheses`
- `AllowDecimalPoint`
- `AllowThousands`
- `AllowExponent`
- `AllowCurrencySymbol`
- `AllowHexSpecifier`
- `Integer`
- `HexNumber`
- `Number`
- `Float`
- `Currency`
- `Any`

For example, passing a hex number:

```
string hex = "AB";
int hexInt = int.Parse(hex, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Or removing parentheses and whitespace:

```
string number = "  (2)  ";
int castedNumber = int.Parse(num, NumberStyles.AllowParentheses |                        
    NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite);
```

Read up about them more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx).

### Update for C# 7

Starting in C# 7, an out variable can be declared in the argument list of a method call ([Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier#calling-a-method-with-an-out-argument)). This allows the C# version of this method to be simplified to a terse one-liner:

```
public static int StrToIntDef(string s, int @default) =>
    int.TryParse(s, out int result) ? result : @default;
```

### References

- [MSDN - Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)
- [MSDN - NumberStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx)

Comment: Well done for taking the question as an opportunity to give your knowledge

Answer (score 10):

```
public static int StrToIntDef(string s, int def)
{
    int temp;
    if (!Int32.TryParse(s, out temp))
        return def;

    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could issue a `TryParse`:

```
int val;
var success = Int.TryParse("1", out val);
```

or you could do a direct conversion:

```
int val = Convert.ToInt32("1");
```

but in short, you don't need your own function. Unless of course you need to specify a default value of something other than `0` when it doesn't convert. If so, then you'll leverage `TryParse` in your method and if it doesn't work then return the default that was passed in.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
int outputInteger;
int.TryParse(inputString, out outputInteger);
```